# Concatenate variable and function name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

We want to concatenate the function name and variable name. This should occur on click of a `<a>` tag.

How can we concatenate the function and variable name?

**Issue:**

- we are getting error message fn_dataId() is not defined

**Desired output:**

`fn_dataId() should be fn_some123();`

**What we tried**

```js
$(function() {
    $('.link').on('click', function() {
      console.log('clicked');
      var dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');
      console.log('data id - ' + dataId);
      
      // What we tried, but didn't work. 
      fn_dataId(); 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-id="some123" class="link">
Click here
</a>
```

Comment: [What is the XY Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  Why is this an issue?

Comment: *`We want`*, no, you want.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Not if he's asking on behalf of his team/more than just himself :)

Comment: @mattytommo psychology ;)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I didn't want to sound selfish that's all. It on behalf of team. :-)

Comment: You are better off using a different model than what you are doing.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm not sure the use case of this it sounds like the dataId might be better off as an argument to a more generic function, but you can possibly solve it using the following:

```
eval("fn_" + dataId + "()")
```

Be wary of eval though - executing anything you take as input from a user is a big security risk

Comment: `eval` is something you should forget even exists. You know, you hit a bus and than you learn to avoid the bus... and you walk... and you're happy...

Answer (score 5):

You can concatenate strings, and use the result as a function using `window["function_name"](args);`:

```js
function fn_some123() {
  console.log('i have been called!');
}

$(function() {
    $('.link').on('click', function() {
      var dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');
      window['fn_' + dataId]();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-id="some123" class="link">
Click here
</a>
```